# How to get ID of row inserted in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an insert working perfectly, but need to get the value of the row it just inserted. Not sure how I can do this. Tried some stuff... didn't work.
Here's my INSERT:

```
//method to insert data
private void insertNewProject()
{
    using (dbPSREntities5 context = new dbPSREntities5())
    {
        //Create a new instance of the tbProject object
        tbProject proj = new tbProject {
            //Add new values to each fields
            ProjectContactInfo = txtContactPhone.Text,
            refDepartmentID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlDepartments.SelectedValue)
        };

       context.tbProjects.AddObject(proj);

       context.SaveChanges();

       id = (int)command.ExecuteScalar; <--- something like this but this doesn't work.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will be automatically updated in your object as soon as `context.SaveChanges();` is called.

```
   context.tbProjects.AddObject(proj);

   context.SaveChanges();

   id = proj.Id;
```

Answer (score 4):

Once you hit `context.SaveChanges()` it will fill the ID into the object.

Assuming your autonumber column is named ID (if not, just use whatever ID column you have)

```
id = proj.ID;
```

You don't have to executescalar or anything like that as EF does that for you.